# How to align two tikz rectangles

Tags: tikz-pgf, horizontal-alignment

I have created two boxes through `tikz` as shown in the code below. The one inside the `enumerate` is shifted a bit. How can I align them?

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{geometry} 
\geometry{a4paper,
 total={210mm,297mm},left=1.5cm,right=1.5cm,top=2cm,bottom=2cm}

\begin{document}

\renewcommand{\thesection}{${Q.}$ \arabic{section}}

\section{Given that}
\tikz \draw[very thick] (0,0) rectangle (\linewidth, 28mm) node [align=right, below left];

\section{Find the cubic}
\begin{enumerate}[leftmargin=5mm,label=\alph*)]
\item $z$

\tikz \draw[very thick] (0,0) rectangle (\linewidth, 28mm) node [align=right, below left];
\end{enumerate}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is shifted by `\leftmargin` that is inserted inside the `enumerate` environment. You may either make `leftmargin` zero or move the rectangle to the left by that amount like I did. Further for the second rectangle you have to use `\textwidth` instead of `\linewidth` as they are not same inside `enumerate`. I have also added `-\pgflinewidth` to avoid `bad boxes.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{geometry}
\geometry{a4paper,left=1.5cm,right=1.5cm,top=2cm,bottom=2cm}

\begin{document}

\renewcommand{\thesection}{${Q.}$ \arabic{section}}

\section{Given that}
\tikz \draw[very thick] (0,0) rectangle (\linewidth-\pgflinewidth, 28mm) node [align=right, below left]{};

\section{Find the cubic}
\begin{enumerate}[leftmargin=5mm,label=\alph*)]
\item $z$

\hspace*{-\leftmargin}\tikz \draw[very thick] (0,0) rectangle (\textwidth-\pgflinewidth, 28mm) node [align=right, below left]{};
\end{enumerate}

\end{document}
```

[image]

In this case, you have fixed left margin as 5mm so you may just use `\hspace*{-5mm}` as well.

Answer (score 0):

Another solution:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{geometry}
\geometry{a4paper,left=1.5cm,right=1.5cm,top=2cm,bottom=2cm}

\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{changepage}
\makeatletter

\newenvironment{wide}
    {\@parboxrestore%
     \begin{adjustwidth}{}{-\leftmargin}%
                \begin{minipage}{\textwidth}
     }{\end{minipage}
     \end{adjustwidth}
     }
\makeatother

    \begin{document}
\renewcommand{\thesection}{${Q.}$ \arabic{section}}

\section{Given that}
\tikz \draw[very thick] (0,0) rectangle (\linewidth, 28mm) node [align=right, below left] {};

\section{Find the cubic}
\begin{enumerate}[leftmargin=5mm,label=\alph*)]
\item xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx

\begin{wide}
 \tikz \draw[very thick] (0,0) rectangle (\linewidth, 28mm);
\end{wide}
\end{enumerate}
    \end{document}
```